# Failed to use ninja-build on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ninja, kaldi

I'm trying to install PyKaldi using its doc and I have installed and configured ninja-build using the following commands:

```
wget https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.8.2/ninja-linux.zip
sudo unzip ninja-linux.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ninja ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja 1 --force
```

and when I run `/usr/bin/ninja --version` I get the version of ninja correctly: 1.8.2

But, when I execute `/usr/bin/ninja -j 6` I get the following error:

> ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory

What is the problem with ninja?